# Why is '=' operator not working on comparing Datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date, datetime

I am trying to fetch records only of the current day. I have used the `=` operator to compare the date but it is not working, if I `subtract` 1 from the current date and then use `>=` operator then it works.

I am putting both queries here.

This code works:

```
1 = (
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(DO.CREATEDON, '') >= GETDATE()-1 
        THEN 1
    END
```

This code doesn't work:

```
1 = (
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(DO.CREATEDON, '') = GETDATE()
        THEN 1
    END
```

Why is the latter code not working?

Comment: Why do you have a `NULL` check?

Comment: Because there is a time difference between the stored date and now? You need to show sample data to illustrate the problem. You should also use the provided datetime functions for adding/subtracting dates. Otherwise its just a guess as to what is being added.

Comment: It's working. The values aren't the same. `GetDate()` includes milliseconds, so it's almost impossible for a stored value to be the same as the current time to the milliseccond

Comment: It is obligatory for us to check `NULLS` in the organisation

Comment: Why the case expression? (Harder to optimize.)

Comment: Check nulls - how?

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: Do you know what using a blank string when the `CREATEDON` column is null will return?

Comment: `It is obligatory for us to check NULLS in the organisation` that phrase contains no information. You only need to check for `NULL` if. you want to *exclude* NULLs from results, only if the field is nullable. You don't do it just because. The way to do that is by usin` IS NULL`, not applying a function. And you definitely don't return an invalid date literal instead of a date. `cast('' as datetime)` returns `1900-01-01`. Not what you want

Comment: FYI you have unclosed brackets in your snippets...

Comment: The entire expression is wrong and would result in a full table scan because that `ISNULL` prevents the server from using any indexes. It's really hard to understand what it does, so it's hard to maintain. If you wanted to find records created in the last second, you could use `where DO.CREATEDON >cast(getdate() as datettime2(0))`. You *DON'T* need to check for NULL, as null values fail all comparisons

Comment: BTW `GetDate() - 1` returns yesterday's date, not the previous second

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GETDATE()` returns a `datetime`, so (for me), right now, using `GETDATE()` returns something like `2021-01-19T09:43:27.123`. It's therefore very unlikely the value in your column `CREATEDON` is going to be the same exact time that `GETDATE()` returns, accurate to the nearest 1/300 of a second.

If your column `CREATEDON` is a date and time value, use inclusive date ranges:

```sql
WHERE DO.CREATEDON >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
  AND DO.CREATEDON < CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())
```

If `CREATEDON` is a `date`, then just `CONVERT` the value of `GETDATE()` to a `date`:

```sql
WHERE DO.CREATEDON = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
```

Note that there's no need for the `ISNULL`, as is the value of `NULL` it is by definition not the value of `GETDATE()`. Also, converting`''` to a date and time value is a little odd; but it would convert to `1900-01-01`, which again, is *not* today. Adding an `ISNULL` on  `DO.CREATEDON` in the `WHERE` will only harm the performance; don't do it.